# Removing multiple DIVs from page, using an array [or a better approach]

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a code to remove all the DIVs that their `<p>` child contains a value from an array.
My code is not working, could you help me with that?
Maybe you have a better approach than me.

---

Here is what I've tried to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var values=['VALUE1','VALUE2'];
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
        $("p:contains(values[i])").closest('.mainDiv').remove();
    }
});
```

And here's the HTML skeleton (the jQuery code would leave only VALUE0 DIV on the page):

```
<div class="clear  mainDiv">
    <div class="clear">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p align="center" class="tgValue">
          <a href="">
            VALUE0
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="clear  mainDiv">
    <div class="clear">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p align="center" class="tgValue">
          <a href="">
            VALUE1
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="clear  mainDiv">
    <div class="clear">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p align="center" class="tgValue">
          <a href="">
            VALUE2
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clear  mainDiv">
    <div class="clear">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p align="center" class="tgValue">
          <a href="">
            VALUE1
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation to add the value of a variable to a string literal

```
$(".mainDiv p:contains(" + values[i] + ")").closest('.mainDiv').remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bmrSq/)

---

Using [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) will return partial matches, like `Value10` will be returned by the selector `:contains(Value1)` - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bmrSq/3/)

If you don't want that to happen, use filter like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var values = ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2'];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        $(".mainDiv p").filter(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).text()) == values[i]
        }).closest('.mainDiv').remove();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bmrSq/4/)

Comment: I really appreciated your help! I hope someday I'll be a good developer like you.

Answer (score 2):

You did mistake into jQuery statement.

replace your code

```
$("p:contains(values[i])").closest('.mainDiv').remove();
```

with

```
$("p:contains('"+values[i]+"')").closest('.mainDiv').remove();
```